# Reading from .txt file and inputting into parrel arrays C++

Tags: c++, arrays, file

Here is the text file.

> 4
>
> MB-1111-1111 1111 222.22
>
> MB-2222-2222 2222 333.33
>
> B1-3333-3333 3333 444.44
>
> 4444 4444 555.55

The 4 at the top is total accounts.
Each line following goes in order of: Account name / PIN / Balance.

How do I read this .txt file and put each of these values into an array?

Heres what I have so far but I'm completely lost.

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int readAccts() {
    ifstream f;
    int accounts_total, max=99999.99, pin, balance;
    char account_name;
    f.open("accounts.txt");
    if (!f.fail()) {
        f >> accounts_total;
        f >> account_name;

        f.close();
        return account_name;
    }
    else {
        cout << "Error reading accounts!" << endl;
        accounts_total = -1;
        f.close();
        return accounts_total;
        
    }
    return accounts_total;
}
```

Comment: You need a loop that reads until it fails to read something like `int count  = 0; while ( count < accounts_total && f>>account_name>>pin>>balance) {do something with account_name, pin, and balance; count++ }` Look into std::vector` and making a `class` or `struct` to help keep track of each entries `account_name`, `pin`, and `balance`.

Answer (score 0):

I would make a few suggestions here.

- Don't use parallel arrays => Better use a class or struct
- Store the objects in a List
- You don't really need to store the number of entries at all

Assume this is the `filename.txt`

> MB-1111-1111 1111 222.22
>
> MB-2222-2222 2222 333.33
>
> B1-3333-3333 3333 444.44
>
> 4444 4444 555.55

```
// create a struct to hold the data
struct Account {
    std::string Name;
    std::string Pin;
    double Balance;
}

// open the file
std::ifstream input( "filename.txt" );
// create a list for all accounts
std::list<Account> Accounts;
// iterate over each line
for( std::string line; getline( input, line ))
{
    // maybe not neccessary but I'm not sure because of the belance and the casting
    std::string name, pin, balance;
    std::stringstream linestream(line);
    // get the line values
    if(linestream >> name >> pin >> balance) {
        Account account;
        // set values for object
        account.Name = name;
        account.Pin = pin;
        // string to double
        account.Balance = std::stod(balance);
        // store account in list
        Accounts.push_back(account);
    }
}
```

---

When you really need arrays:

> 4
>
> MB-1111-1111 1111 222.22
>
> MB-2222-2222 2222 333.33
>
> B1-3333-3333 3333 444.44
>
> 4444 4444 555.55

```
// open the file
std::ifstream input( "filename.txt" );
std::string firstLine;
getline( input, firstLine );
// get the number of following lines
int lines = std::stoi(firstLine);
// create arrays with the capacity of lines
std::string* Names = new std::string[lines];
std::string* Pins = new std::string[lines];
double* Balances = new double[lines];

// iterate over each line
int ctr = 0;
for( std::string line; getline( input, line ))
{
    std::string name, pin, balance;
    std::stringstream linestream(line);
    // get the line values
    if(linestream >> name >> pin >> balance) {
        // store values in corresponding arrays
        Names[ctr] = name;
        Pins[ctr] = pin;
        Balances[ctr] = std::stod(balance);
        // increment counter for next array position
        ctr++;
    }
}
// do something cool with the values
// ...

// free memory after you'r done
delete[] Names;
delete[] Pins;
delete[] Balances;
```

Comment: Groovy. Now can I talk you into putting `linestream >> name >> pin >> balance` into an `if` statement to make sure the reading succeeded?

Comment: My instructor is asking us to do it with arrays as we haven't learned objects/lists yet.

Comment: @Evanjbraun the right way is with a `std::list` or `std::vector` (probably `vector` will be faster), but if that is verboten, you want something like `Account * array = new Account[accounts_total];` and later `delete[] array;` to put the memory away when you are done. Another alternative is to write your own `vector`. Tricky, but very educational.